# Average Answerer's Age (among the tags answered by more than 1000 users with age filled)

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

[**Average Answerer's Age (among the tags answered by more than 1000 users with age filled)**](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1920)

White-bearded aqsaqals of age `33`, who have mastered the principles of `agile` development, use old-school technologies like `VB6`, `COM` and `Oracle`.

Kids of age `28` prefer `css`, `div`-based design of their `wordpress` blogs using `php` and `jquery`.

**Update:**

We could make a horoscope!

When a user logs in, show them the tags corresponding to their current age.

Something along the lines of:

> Today is a good day for `parameters`, `tutorials` and `bash`. `Framework` can surprise you. Beware of `collections` and `learning`.

Comment: People of age 28 are not kids.

Comment: @KennyTM: I knew that white-bearded 33 year olds will meet no objections!

Comment: To those voting to close: we've had well-received *"Here's a query that presents some interesting statistics"* posts to meta in the past. Is this a general claim that these type questions are not good, or a complaint about this on in particular?

Comment: @Kenny: Depends on the 28 year old. It really does.

Comment: @dmckee: In general? I don't know.  I do think shoehorning discussion into the engine for Meta has issues... but this particular question just seemed a bit much.  That said, I did bookmark for upvoting later when I get more votes.

Comment: @The Cat: meta is, at least in part, *for* discussion. Certainly the SOFU engine is not optimal for it, but we use it anyway. Presumably on a "eating your own dogfood" basis.

Answer (score 1):

[Do me do me do me!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtEVy_zjr9Y)

Ohh php is 29. I'm under age.

Answer (score 1):

> *First row and highest age:* tag=agile, average_age=33.81, answer_count=1115

Whoda thunk the average oldest users are the most agile?

Answer (score 1):

Not interesting without the standard deviation for each tag as well. Otherwise the lesson isn't clear...<s>but I'm betting on *"There isn't any significant age variation among the popular tags"*.</s>

---

I take it back. Standard deviations in the 9ish range on populations of 1000+ means standard deviations **of the means** around 0.3. There *is* is statistically significant difference between the limiting cases.

Comment: http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1945